# Excel macro requests access to an external file: removing dependencies

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I download an Excel file and I copied the sheets (I tried also to maintain only the main sheet; figure below) and the macro in a new Excel file; when I try to execute the macro, this message appears:

[image]

I'd like to know where is this dependency and how to remove it.

The macro is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Send_Text_To_WhatsApp()

Dim whatsapp_number As String


Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If sh.Range("H" & i).Value <> "Yes" Then   '' Check Skip

        whatsapp_number = sh.Range("G" & i).Value
    
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%2B" & whatsapp_number & "&text=" & _
        sh.Range("F" & i).Value & "&app_absent=1&send=1"
      
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:08"))

            VBA.SendKeys "~", True
            
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            
             
    End If

Next i

MsgBox "Process Completed", vbInformation

End Sub


Sub Send_Image_To_WhatsApp()

Dim whatsapp_number As String


Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")


Dim tsh As Worksheet
Set tsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")

Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If sh.Range("H" & i).Value <> "Yes" Then  'check skip
    
        whatsapp_number = sh.Range("G" & i).Value
        
        
        ''' Filling the template
        tsh.Range("E4").Value = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("E5").Value = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("E6").Value = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
        tsh.Range("E7").Value = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
        
        
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%2B" & whatsapp_number & "&text=&app_absent=1&send=1"
      
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:08"))
            
            tsh.Range("B2:G9").CopyPicture , xlBitmap
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
            VBA.SendKeys ("^v")
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            VBA.SendKeys "~", True
            
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            
    
    End If
Next i


tsh.Range("E4:E7").ClearContents

MsgBox "Process Completed", vbInformation

End Sub
```

The only formula is in the Text column:

```
="Dear "&B4&","&"%0A"&"Your "&C4&" bill, "&TEXT(D4;"$0.00")&" has been overdue. Your due date was "&TEXT(E4;"D-MMM-YY")&CHAR(10)&". Please make the payment at the earliest." & "%0A" &
```

The macro assigned to the button "Send Text only" is:

[image]

Comment: You need to re-assign the macro in the current workbook to the button.

Comment: Hello @FlexYourData thank you very much for your helpful suggestion.

Comment: @FlexYourData if possible I'd like to ask you another question: which is the right date format? The format &TEXT(E4;"D-MMM-YY") doesn't work

Comment: Is the date in Italian? The rest of the workbook formulas look like they're in English. What is happening with that formula and what do you want to happen? It will be easiest if you edit your question, or start a new question. BTW, did reassigning the macro fix the problem with the reference to the original workbook?

Comment: @FlexYourData yes I think it's in English because I copied it from an English Excel; by pushing the button, the first output date is DD-01-YY instead of 15-1-20. Your solution about the reassignment works very well! Thank you a lot!

Comment: To avoid confusion between languages, I recommend you re-type the dates in this format: YYYY-MM-DD, so that first row is 2020-01-15, second is 2020-01-19, and so on. That will ensure they are actual dates and not just text. Then try the macro again.